# How to invalidate the form (or failure message on clicking save) if the user chooses text that is not recommended in <p:autoComplete>

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I am having this dialog form (using primefaces 3, jsf 2.0)

[image]

With my text field is like this:

```
<p:autoComplete id="zipCodeCity" queryDelay="300" minQueryLength="1" 
 forceSelection="true"
 styleClass="zipcodeCityStyle" process="@this" maxlength="40" 
 completeMethod="#{logic.loadZipCodeCity}" var="city" 
 itemLabel="#{(city.zipCode.length() > 0 ? city.zipCode.concat(' ') : '')}#{city.name}" 
 itemValue="#{city}" value="#{data.selectedCity}" 
 converter="cityConverter" effect="blind" />
```

My button on save like this:

```
 <p:commandButton id="btnSave"
  value="Save"
  actionListener="#{logic.save}"
  global="true" process="addressEditorFrm"
  update="addressEditorFrm" />
```

The GOAL: is not to let the user save something out of the recommended selections (in p:autoComplete). Ideally, when user types something not in the selections and clicks save, it shouldn't submit dialog form to the server but generate growl error message on the client side that says "hey, you have to choose something out of selections recommended from the server", and this dialog form should still be on util the user chooses again or click cancel. In short, I want to force the users to input in the items that exist on the server database.

Is there way to achieve this? or to modify primefaces in some way? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Found it.

`require="true"` and `requiredMessage="Your message here"` solve this.